# App crash on iOS 5 - Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

My app is working very fine on iPhone and Simulator with iOS 6, but when i try to run on iPhone/Simulator with iOS 5 the app crashes

The error is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint'

I'm not using Autolayout on Interface Builder Document.

Could anyone help me?

**Autolayout is not checked**

Comment: How can i make it?
Yes I'm of Hungarian origins, you too?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

make sure you have unselected use autolayout in interfacebuild

[image]

Comment: yes autolayout is unselected =\ and my app crash with any nib

Answer (score 12):

You've been burned.  NSLayoutConstraint only exists on iOS 6. You have to check to see if it's there, and if it's not, you have to do something else.

Comment: i'm sorry, i not understood your answer, how can i check it?

Comment: That call to NSLayoutConstraint isn't in iOS 5.  It's iOS 6 only.  You're using some technology that is only iOS 6.  To find it, download an older version of xcode, like 4.4.1, and build for iOS 5, the compiler will show an error where you've used iOS 6 only calls.  You'll probably need a developer account to get 4.4.1, but if you're serious, you'll spend the $99

Comment: Thanks!
It solve my problem.
I found that 2 Storyboards. One in English and the other in Portuguese and I unselect Autolayout just on English Storyboard

Thanks!!